# Verify that the following is an isomorphism $T$:$P_1$ → $R^2; T[p(x)]=[p(0),p(1)]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, group-isomorphism

$T$:**$P_1$** → $R^2; T[p(x)]=[p(0),p(1)]$

I need help, not sure how to start. Thanks in advance!

$P$=Polynomials

Apparently this theorem is meant to help:
 If $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension $n$, a linear transformation $T:V→W$ is an isomorphism if it is either one-to-one or onto.

Comment: So $P_1$ means polynomials of the form $ax+b$?

Comment: I'm assuming yes, the question unfortunately does not specify.

Comment: Here is a sketch. Given this form note that every polynomial is entirely determined by $a$ and $b$ so intuitively it's dimension should be two and I leave it to you to make that as formal as the class requires. Making the substitutions for $p(0)$ and $p(1)$ we see that the polynomial determined by the coefficient pair $(a,b)$ maps to the point $(b,a+b) \in R^2$. Note that given a point of the form $(b,a+b)$ allows you to recover the value of $b$ directly and the value of $a$ by subtracting off the $b$ from $a+b$. This means the map is invertible which proves it is both one-to-one and onto.

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that $T$ is a linear transformation? This is routine and I will assume that you have verified this. A linear transformation is one-to-one if and only of $Tp=0$ implies $p=0$. So consider $p(x)=ax+b$ in $P_1$. Suppose $Tp=0$. Then $(p(0),p(1))$ is the zero vector in $\mathbb R^{2}$ which means $p(0)=0$ and $p(1)=0$. But $p(x)=ax+b$ so we get $0+b=0$ and $a+b=0$. These two equations imply $a=b=0$ which means $p$ is the zero polynomial or the zero element of $P_1$. We have proved that $T$ is one-to-one. Since $\mathbb R^{2}$ has dimension 2 we only have to prove that $P_1$ also has dimension 2. For this verify that $p_1(x)=1$ and $p_2(x)=x$ form a basis for $P_1$.